# Listing top level terms in views including those without children

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

My vocabulary looks like this

Level 1a

- Child a
- Child b
- Child c

Level 1b

- Child a
- Child b
- Child c

Level 1c

Level 1d

- Child a
- Child b
- Child c

Level 1e

I have managed to display parents and children terms using Taxonomy term: Parent term and filter on (Parent) Taxonomy term: Parent term (not empty). But terms without children on the same level with "parent" are not displayed.

To get the children I used filter “(Parent) Taxonomy term: Parent term (not empty)”. If I set the same filter to “is empty”, I get all level 1 terms including those terms without children just like I want it. So right now it seems like an either-or situation. I can only get the top terms or the children terms but not both.

How do I get the top level terms including those without children and corresponding child terms for those with children?

Comment: Why have we created view for this? Are we using it as an Expose filter in views?

Answer (score 1):

If you add a filter to parent term = "empty (NULL)" it will display all terms that have no parent above them.

For more detailed steps, try this blog post I wrote: http://fdiv.net/2012/08/11/taxonomy-views-browser-arbitrary-depth

Answer (score 0):

The case seems to be old, but just in case someone bumps into it searching for help.
Just try [Views Tree](http://drupal.org/project/views_tree) module, which provides a display plugin (next to grid, table, list, etc.). You'll be able to show the taxonomy exactly as asked here.

Answer (score -1):

[Taxonomy Menu](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu) Module can help you with this.